# point website URL in safari to iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, safari

I know that by using custom url schemes I can put a link in Safari that will point to my app (eg. "myApp://"). What I'm wondering is if there's a way I can set up a URL such as "http://myApp.com" to point to my app instead. The reason for this is that I have a web app on my site that can be used to open URLs. But the iPhone app has many more features and I'd like to have that open instead of the web app when it's available.

Answer (score 0):

u can check for the agent, and if the agent is iphone, redirect the url to the custom url scheme